# Can't install modules via pip, said not supported

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-wheel

I am new to python. And I want to install some modules, but it kept telling me the wheel is not supported. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Details:

```
python ver. 3.6.4 x64
Pillow-5.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Here is what I got when I tried to install the module via `pip`.

```
C:\Python\Scripts>pip install Pillow-5.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

> Pillow-5.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

When I run

```
import pip
print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
```

I get the following output:

> [('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win_amd64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('py3', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py36', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py35', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]

Comment: Have you tried **pip install Pillow**.

Comment: You can try pip install pillow=5.0.0 as pointed by Reck.   
You can download .tar.gz file and then run pip install pillow.tar.gz(I have done this and works fine if all dependencies a re satisfied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this it works for me, run in CMD

```
python -m pip install pillow --trusted-host='pypi.python.org'
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but there are several lines of red content.

Comment: Have you tried **pip install pillow**. I mean why adding **-m flag**. And **--trusted-host** not required.

Comment: Which kind of red content post it here

Comment: In my case, it doesn't work  pip install pillow so it tried to download from trusted host

Comment: @Harsh Bhut Here it is. <br/> Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main status = self.run(options, args) <br/> Does it matter?

Comment: Is it working fine now? because you thank @reck and also put an error what I gonna suppose it works or not? if not works then what you supposed to do with pillow library? what is your code sample?

Comment: @HarshBhut You are right, the command 'pip install pillow' automatically downloads a 32 bit version module, while my python is x64. Still can't import it in the shell. I have just started learning an image recognition course. It is required to install numpy and pillow to bulid the enviornment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
pip install pillow
```